# Javascript URL encode a string but do not encode again the part of string already encoded

Tags: javascript, string, encoding, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

I have something like this:

```
<script id="myscript">
var myscript=encodeURI(document.getElementById("myscript").innerHTML);
var msg="--this string is already URL encoded--";

/* Do some HTTP setting up here with XMLHttpRequest() object. */
send(httpcontent);
</script>
```

Since I plan on sending the script along with the already encoded message, I do not want to encode the message again. When I call `encode()` in the script above, it will encode everything within the `script`, including `msg`, which is already encoded. I want to just encode everything within the script tags, except what is within `msg` since it is already encoded.

So in this case, `httpcontent` will include both `msg` **and** `myscript`

Thanks

Comment: Why are you calling `encodeURI` then? Also, how do you expect people to help you if you don't show the code of the `send()` function?

Comment: Updated question, pls check